# WSO2 API Manager and Analytics doesn't connect on docker

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to implement WSO2 API manager with the Analytics solution in K8s (local machine- Docker K8s)

I am using the APIM 3.2.0 image the same version image for analytics

Both the API manager and the analytics solution is getting deployed and I could access the analytics dashboard, publisher and devportal. I can create and call APIs from publisher and devportal. However, the analytics solution doesn't hold any of my API data.

I have deployed the Worker, then the API manager, and then the dashboard in the same order as suggested [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/)

After the analytics server is started

I **cannot** see the below message in the Analytics worker

```
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} - user admin connected
```

[image]

I have enabled the apim.analytics in my deployment.toml file (as a config map).

```
[apim.analytics]
enable = true
store_api_url = "https://localhost:7444"
```

Please throw some insights on the missing part

Comment: Please check your configs with this- https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/v3.2.0.4/advanced/am-pattern-1/templates/am/instance-1/wso2am-pattern-1-am-conf.yaml#L124-L136

Comment: This is the APIM deployment.toml to connect with analytics

Comment: Docker compose stuff can be found here - https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/blob/v3.2.0.3/docker-compose/apim-with-analytics/conf/apim/repository/conf/deployment.toml#L95-L106